# Removing spacing between table cells for a single row only

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'd like to know if it's possible to remove the space between table cells on a web page for *only one* row. I've seen lots of examples showing how to do this for the entire table, but I have a table whose header would look much nicer with no spacing between its cells. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- I'd like these cells to NOT have any space between them -->
    <td>ColHeader1</td>
    <td>ColHeader2</td>
    <td>ColHeader3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- I'd like these cells to have normal spacing -->
    <td>NormalCol1</td>
    <td>NormalCol2</td>
    <td>NormalCol3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried setting padding to 0 in the row and in the cells, but that doesn't do anything for me.  The `border-collapse` property can only be applied to the table element, and the same goes for `border-spacing`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try to use tables in better way. So if you have header in your table make it like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
       ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    (table content goes here>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now you can easily separate styles for header and table body.

`<thead>` was made specifically for table header sections, because they are widely used. If you have a footer in your table, you can also use the `<tfoot>` tag (but keep in mind that is has to appear before the `<tbody>` tag).

Hope this is what you're looking for.

**Edit:** 
Another possibility is to create two tables, one for headers and one for content. You could also make headers out of `div` elements and style them in table fashion. As pointed out in the comments, it is impossible to apply different values of `cellspacing` or `cellpadding`.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  (headers)
</table>
<br />
<table cellspacing="2">
  (content)
</table>
```

Yet another option is to create the entire table from `div` elements, but for tabular content it is better to use `table`.

Comment: Yes, that was just a quick example to be sure my meaning was clear.  The fact remains the the border-spacing and border-collapse can ONLY target the table tag itself.  Unless I find another set of css properties that can remove the spacing, <thead> will be no more useful than <td>.

Comment: I can see your point now. Only thing that comes to my mind now is to make 2 tables, one above an another with `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` property set to 0. It is impossible to set different `cellspacing` values to some rows as well as you can't set different `width` to cells in the same column. Other solution is to create tables from `<div>` elements and `display: table-cell` property of CSS. See http://jimbarraud.com/2008/06/04/the-magical-css-table-cell/ for more info. I can't really see other choices here.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I thought I'd ask, though.  ;)

I'm using GWT, so the html is being generated for me.  I guess what I'll do is make a custom widget that contains the elements I need, span the entire first row, and add my composited widget as that cell's widget.   Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: If you want, you could add the use-another-table suggestion as an answer, and I could mark it accepted.  I guess that's what we should do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `<th>` (table header) instead of the `<td>`s on the first table row and target that with css.  besides that there is a css first-child selector (not compatible with all browsers)

```
table tr:first-child td{
   /* css code for no spacing here */
}
```